# How to get the content of every cell in a row from a dataframe using itertuples() on Python? Pandas related

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

Let's suppose I have the following `df`:

```
       0      0      1               1    2       2     3        3      4    4    5     5         
0  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas None            
1  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Arena     
2  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Marron    
3  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Purpura    
4  Fondo Oceano Cuerpo Cuerpo cangrejo Ojos Antenas Color Amarillo Pinzas None Puas Verde
```

I know I can merge `.itertuples(index=False)` and `.iloc[[0]]` this way to print the contents of each cell from that row:

```
for i in df.iloc[[0]].itertuples(index=False):
    print(i)
```

**Output:**

> Pandas(_0='Fondo', _1='Oceano', _2='Cuerpo', _3='Cuerpo cangrejo', _4='Ojos', _5='Antenas', _6='Color', _7='Amarillo', _8='Pinzas', _9='None', _10='Puas', _11='None')

But I don't know how could I improve the sentence above to get the following output for that particular row (i.e. `0`):

**Desired output:**

> Fondo
>
> Oceano
>
> Cuerpo
>
> Cuerpo cangrejo
>
> Ojos
>
> Antenas
>
> Color
>
> Amarillo
>
> Pinzas
>
> None
>
> Puas
>
> None

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By slicing with double square brackets you get a (2D) DataFrame.

It looks like you're trying to loop in 1D. You should use [`Series.iteritems`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
for _, e in df.iloc[0].iteritems():
    print(e)
```

output:

```
Fondo
Oceano
Cuerpo
Cuerpo
cangrejo
...
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I appreciate it!, may you also tell me how could the program above evaluate if the `e` counter has stored the last cell from the row before finishing? I mean, something like `if last_element(e) == True: print("This is the last element)`

Comment: `e` is not a counter, this is the element. You could use an extra counter and the known length of the dataframe (`len(df)`) to identify the last row